# Forcing -i from a command line script

Tags: python, command-line-interface

We have a module that is really useful to run interactively as a commandline script.

`python -i tool`

All users are python coders. So while there has been talk of making an interactive commandline app, the power of just being able to use the tool with code nobody wants to abandon, and it would be too much to recode that kind of power, unless there is something obvious.

Literally the only annoyance is having to type

`python -i tool`

Because everyone types

`./tool`

gets an unhelpful message and remembers.

I was going to improve the message. But I wondered if I could just make it work. When the script is run can it run itself with `-i`. If the script is a different name from the module, it can be a shell script. But the same file? Can I run python interactively just from the

`if __name__ == "__main__":`

bit?

Comment: would adding `subprocess.run("python -i tool")` in the program body solve your issue? It isn't exactly clear what you're saying here, but [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#.run) allows you to run shell commands from inside a python program. Don't forget to put in `import os` in the intro, to allow for use of the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @Mathchiller: If you want to import `subprocess`, that's `import subprocess`, not `import os`. Anyway, there's a better way (see dupe target).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the dupe. Exactly right. It didn't suggest. My search foo is weak.